# Difference between "controlled release" vs "prolonged release"

Tags: pharmacology, medicine

My sister is using the epilepsy drug Tegretol which has both CR and retard (previous naming for prolonged release according to https://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/product/5932/smpc) versions in different countries. Given the active ingredient is the same (carbamazepine), would there be any difference between the effects of the two drugs in terms of preventing seizures?

Here are the boxes for the two versions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the sake of your sister's safety **please** consult with a pharmacist or other medical professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first box contains **Tegretol Retard**, which is an old name for what is now known as **Tegretol Prolonged Release** ([medicines.org.uk](https://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/product/5932/pil)).

The second box contains **Tegretol CR**, which means **controlled-release** ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12073283)).

[Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/uk/tegretol-cr-200mg-tablets-leaflet.html) says:

> Your medicine is called Tegretol 200mg prolonged-release
>   Tablets/Tegretol CR 200mg Tablets or Tegretol 400mg prolonged-release
>   Tablets/Tegretol CR 400mg Tablets but will be referred to as Tegretol
>   prolonged-release Tablets throughout this leaflet.

**Concluding from that, Tegretol CR200 is the same as Tegretol Retard, which is now known as Tegretol Prolonged Release.**

Saying that, it is a doctor who prescribes drugs and who can answer such questions.